# Prevent Jade/Pug from Erroring when objects are undefined

Tags: express, pug

Is there a way to prevent Jade/Pug from throwing errors when feeding it (undefined) nested Objects? Everytime this happens the whole page breaks instead of just leaving out that one missing piece of information.

#### Current Behaviour:

```
- foo = undefined
span= foo.bar // Error: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined, page Breaks
```

#### Workaround & desired Behaviour:

```
- foo = undefined
if foo
    span= foo.bar // leaves out this span, renders rest of the page
```

I would love to have this behaviour as standard without checking everytime wether or not the object exists. Especially with deeper nested objects this gets really painful.

Comment: This is pretty standard in terms of the way JS is done, especially if you're being a bit messy with variables. Checkout a contributor's thoughts on the matter https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/719 . 

Because pug is a JS interpreter, you get a lot of power, but this is one of the tradeoffs you will have to deal with. Besides, `if varname` really isn't that bad

Answer (score 2):

You could try the good ole' ternary operator.

```
span= foo ? foo.bar : null
```

From what I can tell, `pug` will still render elements with empty string  or null values. You'll end up with `<span></span>`. This feature is problematic in the case of `li` elements; you'll get bullet points with no content.